# How to trace the operations performed on a table in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Masterinsertupdatedelete (@id            INTEGER,
                                          @first_name    VARCHAR(10),
                                          @last_name     VARCHAR(10),
                                          @salary        DECIMAL(10, 2),
                                          @city          VARCHAR(20),
                                          @StatementType NVARCHAR(20) = '')
AS
  BEGIN
      IF @StatementType = 'Insert'
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO employee
                        (id,
                         first_name,
                         last_name,
                         salary,
                         city)
            VALUES     ( @id,
                         @first_name,
                         @last_name,
                         @salary,
                         @city)
        END

      IF @StatementType = 'Select'
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM   employee
        END

      IF @StatementType = 'Update'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE employee
            SET    first_name = @first_name,
                   last_name = @last_name,
                   salary = @salary,
                   city = @city
            WHERE  id = @id
        END
      ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Delete'
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM employee
            WHERE  id = @id
        END
  END
```

Now when we execute this SP and employee table is being updated, then we should be able to track it.

Comment: Directly after the update it could check the [@@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

please read this article
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2003/simple-process-to-track-and-log-sql-server-stored-procedure-use/

After read that you can do your own log by add the filed for the
Sql statment execution

Put your statment in a string to insert it into the log table

This solution need more work but its very good to log all your transaction